Examples of topological spaces that closed+boundness implies compactness
One familiar example of such one is the Euclideans. Recently I learnt that the space of holomorphic functions over an open set $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ also has this property. The formal statement is as follows (Reference: Joseph L Taylor, Several Complex Variables with Connections to Algebraic Geometry and Lie Groups Page 30):

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be open, $H(U)$ the set of all holomorphic functions defined on $U$, given the seminorm $\|\cdot\|_K$ for each compact subset $K\subset U$. Then every closed bounded subset of $H(U)$ is compact, where $A\subset H(U)$ is bounded means $\{\|f\|_K:f\in A\}$ is bounded for each compact subset $K\subset U$.

I have already seen examples that such a property fails in general topological spaces, and this is the first time I encounter an example besides $\mathbb{R}^n$ where a closed and bounded set is compact. So my question is, is there any other spaces such that this property holds, or do we have some classification on spaces with this property holds?

For normed vector spaces, this is the case iff the space is finite dimensional (Riesz's lemma). For function spaces with the uniform norm on a well chosen topological space (my memories are blurry, I do not study this at all nowadays), I believe that adding the "equicontinuity" condition gives a similar statement (i.e. compact = closed + bounded + equicontinuous). That's as far as my knowledge on the topic goes.

What is a bounded set in a topological space?

In locally convex theory, Montel's theorem was the reason to call barrelled spaces with the property that all closed bounded sets are compact Montel spaces.  As a rule of thumb, almost all locally convex spaces naturally appearing in analysis are either Banach or otherwise Montel (and typically even Schwartz or even nuclear spaces).
Examples are the space $C^\infty(\Omega)$ of smooth functions on an open set (or a smooth manifold), the space $\mathscr S(\mathbb R^d)$ of rapidly decreasing functions, the space $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ of smooth functions with compact support, the space $A(\Omega)$ of real analytic functions, all their duals endowed with the topology of uniform convergence on compact sets.
More examples are duals of barrelled locally convex spaces with the weak$^*$ topology (but these spaces are hardly ever barrelled, sometimes they are called semi-Montel).

Here is a criterion similar to what you asked for in the question. If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we say that $E\subseteq X$ is totally bounded if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a finite collection of open balls of radius $<\varepsilon$ which cover $E$. Every totally bounded set is bounded, but the converse is not true in general. However, every bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is totally bounded. A subset of a complete metric space $(X,d)$ is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded.

Think of this answer more as a comment-answer that would be a bit too long to fit into a comment. I'm sure there are more knowledgeable people who would be able to answer with more confidence and more insight.
This property for a topological vector space (TVS) $X$ of having its bounded closed sets be compact is called the Heine-Borel property.
Just like any such property, it's probably going to be quite hard to classify such spaces besides the already simple definition, but like in Fançois's comment above, there are some known properties about spaces which have the Heine-Borel property (HBP for short), the first of which is the fact that normable TVSes have the HBP iff they are finite-dimensional.
Moreover, by Theorem 1.23 from Rudin's Functional Analysis for example, TVSes which have the HBP and in which there exists a bounded neighbourhood of $0$ (such spaces are called locally bounded) have to be finite-dimensional too.
According to Wikipedia, there are also known sufficient conditions to have the HBP, such as having a quasi-complete nuclear space or a Montel space, but that's starting to get out of my "range of expertise" so to speak.
Finally, another known concrete example of a space having the HBP is the space $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\Omega)$ of smooth functions on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, which is a Fréchet space when given the topology induced by the following seminorms:
$$p_i : u \in \mathcal{C}^\infty(\Omega) \,\longmapsto \sum_{|\alpha| \leq i} \sup_{x \in K_i} \left|\partial^\alpha u(x)\right|$$
where $(K_i)$ is an exhaustion of $\Omega$ by compact sets, i.e. $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} K_i = \Omega$ and $K_i \subset \mathring{K_{i+1}}$.
You can define the same type of topology on $\mathcal{C}^k(\Omega)$, $k$ finite, but they will not have the HBP, as there is a counterexample of a bounded closed set not being compact, so $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\Omega)$ is special in that regard.
A reference I can give for these last spaces, if you can read French that is, is Claude Zuily's Eléments de distributions et d'équations aux dérivées partielles, first chapter, but those are likely some classical facts which are proved somewhere else that's accessible.
